Spring OAuth2 server horizontal scaling causing auth failure
I am currently running a Spring OAuth2 auth server in my application which is running on PCF. Recent expansion in the application means that now we are seeing more load on the application and I want to increase the number of instances for this server, however, once I do that, because my logic is based on generating random keys for the token, each instance is giving a different response.
My caller application, when checking for token, can get one from any one of the instances and the main application may refer to any other instance to validate, this causes a token mismatch and auth fails.
In the below code, I have tried to hard code the RSA public key, RSA private key, key ID and even token parameters like "iat", but I am not getting a single consistent response from the server.
This is how my RSA key pairs are being generated, as you can see, random sequences are used, so each instance will generate its own random sequence:
private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            SecureRandom se = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, se);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

This is how I am using the generated keys in RSAKey object and creating the JWKSet, which is then returned inside a ImmutableJWKSet object:
 public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey(); // From the method above
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .issueTime(null).expirationTime(null)
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
}

I tried to use a hardcoded RSA public key, private key and key ID, something like below, but always getting different tokens:
private RSAPublicKey publicKey() {
        String publicKeyPem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n"
                + "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmbUIg34wINnYnjAkdmLj\r\n"
                + "4HtVpM7H0/T4aPAdoLLt9aNNgaBbQ0qS6iEtt1VHiua87Spp3DQpJ0Nyo65hYVgc\r\n"
                + "5KpalBbhH+Bz0Mj9TR/24XGV3VOfmy0pIRZJ4EJZS8WP7+lH0XUyhzVmAEYwaWok\r\n"
                + "LLpmmXHRxXk02KkEtgObL0TyEko3ygxf6O0d0+XuX9GchzBLMR+lt4gOoOld1w2L\r\n"
                + "7CJ9UmF1diesr979xs+nMcST1VkWvR3QBg2cchwZEe5VR/+FD7US1s/mPNxumAgi\r\n"
                + "uJzyLxLNeaCjWueZ4zdj4586YNxFOrLg6j6Ud3bpoX37rnNWWgnuZjNejS6MB5Ov\r\n"
                + "4QIDAQAB\r\n"
                + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        try {
            String publicKeyPemContent = publicKeyPem.replaceAll("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replaceAll("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replaceAll("\\s", "");
            byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPemContent);
            X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse public key", e);
        }
    }

I also changed and hardcoded the key ID, but no luck so far
I need a way for this to work, multiple instances of this server to not fail auth, if expecting all instances return the same token is not the best idea, I am open to try something else
Thanks in advance

As you can image everytime a new instance is started a new key pair will be generated. The best way to go is to generate physical key pair and store them in files then use them. You can proceed like this:
1- Generate rsa key pairs using openssl in your terminal
# create keys
$ openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048

# get the public key
$ openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -pubout -out public.pem

# get private key in PKCS#8 format
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -out private.pem

Then
2- Create a rsakeys directory under resources folder and put the public.pem and private.pem files
3- Add configuration properties into your application.propertie|yml
rsa-keys.public-key=classpath:rsakeys/public.pem
rsa-keys.private-key=classpath:rsakeys/private.pem

4- Create a configuration class which will contain property refencing those keys:
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rsa-keys")
public record RsaKeyProperties(RSAPublicKey publicKey, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
}

Then use this class to configure your jwkSource bean:
 @Bean
 public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource(RsaKeyProperties rsa) {
        
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(rsa.publicKey())
                .privateKey(publicKey.privateKey())
                .keyID("secured-key-id")
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
}

With that, everything should work. Do not forget to externalize your key pair in a secured place like Vault, they should not be visible in production.

Hi, if you notice the third code block in my question, I am using an RSA key hardcoded as String and converting it into the appropriate RSA Public Key Object. The same I followed for RSA private key as well, and yet, the server will return a different final token. I suspect there is some internal parameter perhaps which is making this token different everytime?

Did you try the solution I gave you? Also, try setting a static key id instead of UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Hi, sorry for the delay, yes I tried everything exactly as you suggested. Created the RSA public and private keys using openssl, put them in .pem format in the resources, then defined a record class with these keys as well. Finally, gave a single hardcoded value for keyID. I also configured default values for "issueTime" and "expirationTime" as I thought those might be introducing randomness. However, after every restart, the final token is always different. One thing I noticed though, the first 38 characters of the token are always same
